Identifying Source of a Permission in Azure Resource Manager (ARM)
We've encountered a permission that's new to us and would greatly appreciate it if the ARM team could assist us in identifying its source. The permission is Microsoft_Resources/marketplace/purchase/action.
We are trying to understand the origin and purpose of this specific permission. Any insights or documentation references that could help us identify where this permission comes from and how it should be used would be highly appreciated.
Thanks !
We have reviewed the available documentation and searched through various forums and resources to find information about the Microsoft_Resources/marketplace/purchase/action permission.
We also attempted to trace its origin within our Azure Resource Manager (ARM) configurations and logs but were unable to pinpoint its source or understand its specific use case.
We were expecting to find detailed documentation or examples that explain the purpose and application of this permission, but our efforts have not yielded any conclusive results so far.

Try to connect wth Microsoft Support or open a GitHub issue in the Azure REST API documentation repository for clarification on the Microsoft_Resources/marketplace/purchase/action @Amir


Identifying Source of a Permission in Azure Resource Manager (ARM)

The permission you mentioned is Microsoft.Resources/marketplace/purchase/action  is a section of Azure's Role-Based Access Control system which only relates to marketplace.
In order to access this, we need relevent permissions to use the resources from the marketplace. To have the relevent permissions to access the refer the microsoft document.

You can review your roles using following commands
Get-AzRoleAssignment -Scope /subscriptions/<subscription-id> | Where-Object {$_.RoleDefinitionName -like "*marketplace*"}

Get-AzRoleDefinition | Where-Object {$_.Actions -contains "Microsoft.Resources/marketplace/purchase/action"}

For futher info and information relates to this please reaching out to Microsoft Support or consulting the Azure community forum its always better to contact them for configuring permissions for marketplace purchases.
Refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/azure-marketplace-overview
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/role/assignment?view=azure-cli-latest#az-role-assignment-list

Quick q about this...
I have checked the Manifest JSON of Microsoft.Resources and i couldn't find this permission.
Sharing the link to the JSON file:
link
Can i consider that this permission is a zombie permission?
